# Configuring Tailwind theme from Typescript file in Angular

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, es6-modules

I want to set up the Tailwind theme in .ts files, to take advantage of typing and reuse the defined values in my typescript code, from my Angular services.

I created project with Angular CLI 13.1:

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "test-project-tailwind",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "3.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  }
}
```

I installed tailwindcss:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init
```

I setup tailwind config :

```js
// tailwind.config.js

import theme from 'src/theme/theme'

module.exports = {
  darkMode: false,
  theme: theme
}
```

```js
// src/theme/theme.ts

export default {
  colors: {
    blue: 'blue',
    red: 'red'
  },
}
```

Then I got the following error on `ng serve`:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module: project-path\tailwind.config.js

> require() of ES modules is not supported.

> require() of project-path\tailwind.config.js from project-path\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains
> "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
> Instead rename tailwind.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from project-path\package.json.

Any idea how could I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try naming your `tailwind.config.js` to end in `.cjs` instead?

Comment: Yes, the file is just not loaded.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`

Comment: Are you using `require()` any where? like in your global css file or `theme.ts`?

Comment: No, `require()` is called from `project-path\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js` to load my config file `tailwind.config.js`.

Comment: This is a file from `node_modules`...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and although I tried a couple of things (i.e. using a `.cjs` file), I didn't have any luck. I finally got this working by simply removing `type: module`, which was not the most ideal thing. I think I may have explicitly set `type: module` in my package.json just because I thought it was a best practice, but it's not set by angular itself. If you were to just run `ng new`, the module type isn't explicitly set (therefore defaults to commonjs).

In my case, I also had to install postcss as tailwind needs at least 8.0 or greater.

Comment: I tried removing `type: module` but then I just got `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` in tailwind.config.js` lign 1 when running `ng serve`. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I see your config now, you are using `import` for the `src/theme/theme`. could you make the `src/theme/theme` a `module.exports` and then use `var theme = require('src/theme/theme')` require instead of using the import?